# Salesforce Live Chat api concurrent requests

Tags: ajax, tabs, salesforce, chat

I've tried to extend my chatbot with salesforce live agent api. So I've implemented all the process, and chat works correct, except one thing - It won't work on multiple tabs. When one tab have `long polling` connection (left side on the screenshot), and I open new tab (right side) - old tab (left) receive:

```
409 Conflict
Duplicate Message Observer
```

[image]

Is it possible, and can I use multiple tabs with salesforce long polling connection on my online shop? (it is general situation, when customer has many tabs, and each of them should be with the same chat)

I use salesforce `Messages` api endpoint: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't work with multiple tabs on the Salesforce. You can make the backend part, where you can make a locker. (only one request pass to the SF, but all other waits for the master-request